# Change a full column of such as F01U123456 to F.01U.123.456

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vba

Is it possible to change a full column of such as `F01U123456` into `F.01U.123.456` with an Excel formula, or would it require a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula is sufficient:

```
=LEFT(A1)&"."&MID(A1,2,3)&"."&MID(A1,5,3)&"."&MID(A1,8,3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was of great help. :)